# JsonSchemaGenerator Not Setting Fields to required = false

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonschema

I'm using a `JsonSchemaGenerator` from `JSON.NET` against a series of models to output the respective JSON schemas into a dictionary like below.

```
JsonSchemaGenerator generator = new JsonSchemaGenerator()
{
    UndefinedSchemaIdHandling = UndefinedSchemaIdHandling.UseTypeName,
};
List<Type> modelTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    .GetTypes()
    .ToList()
    .Where(t => t.Namespace == "MyApp.Models")
    .ToList();

foreach (Type type in modelTypes)
{
    JsonSchema schema = generator.Generate(type, jsonSchemaResolver, false);
    schemaDictionary.Add(type, schema);
}
```

This is working properly with the exception of the vales set for the `required` attribute. No matter how I decorate the model properties, the fields *always* are shown to be `"required":true` as shown below:

```
"FirstName": {
   "required": true,
   "type": "string"
}
```

However, in code my model is decorated as such:

```
[JsonProperty(Required = Required.Default)]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

Looking at the Json.Net [documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty.htm), setting to `Required.Default` should result in the property *not* being required in the schema:

> "Default - 0 - The property is **not** required. The default state."

Any idea on what I'm doing incorrectly and need to change so that `FirstName` property is output in the schema as `"required": false`? I do *not* want to have to generate and hand massage all of these schemas.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `Required` enumeration controls which values can the property have: whether null values are allowed or not. To control the  `"required"` property in the json schema, meaning whether the json string must contain the actual property or not, you need to use the `DefaultValueHandling` or `NullValueHandling` enumerations while generating the schema. Lets say that we have the following class:

```
public class Person
{
        [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Default)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }    
}
```

Generated schema with JSON.NET for this class looks like this:

```
{
    "id": "MyApp.Models.Person",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "FirstName": {
            "required": true,
            "type": [
                "string",
                "null"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This schema indicates that a json string must have the property `FirstName` and it is allowed for this property to have null values.

By changing the `Required` attribute from `Default` to `Always` we'll get the following schema:

```
{
    "id": "MyApp.Models.Person",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "FirstName": {
            "required": true,
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

This schema indicates that a json string must have the property `FirstName` and it is NOT allowed for this property to have null values.

To get what you want, you'll need to include the `DefaultValueHandling` or `NullValueHandling` enumerations. Something like this:

```
public class Person
{
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Default, DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }    
}
```

Generated schema from this class would look like this:

```
{
    "id": "MyApp.Models.Person",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "FirstName": {
            "type": [
                "string",
                "null"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This schema indicates that the `FirstName` property is not required in the json string, but if it is present, it may have null value. The same effect can be achieved if you use `DefaultValueHandling.IgnoreAndPopulate` enum value or if you switch to the `NullValueHandling` property instead of `DefaultValueHandling` property and set its value to `NullValueHandling.Ignore`.